# uppercase first letter of each words (utf8) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ucfirst

EDIT: Adding `CHARSET utf8` to input param and output make it works.
i found this code snippet to convert first letter of every words to uppercase

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION CAP_FIRST (INPUT VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8)

RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8

DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE i INT;

    SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(INPUT);
    SET INPUT = LOWER(INPUT);
    SET i = 0;

    WHILE (i < len) DO
        IF (MID(INPUT,i,1) = ' ' OR i = 0) THEN
            IF (i < len) THEN
                SET INPUT = CONCAT(
                    LEFT(INPUT,i),
                    UPPER(MID(INPUT,i + 1,1)),
                    RIGHT(INPUT,len - i - 1)
                );
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN INPUT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

while it works for ascii string; it doesn't work for utf8

like when i do `select cap_first('tiếng việt');` ; i'm getting `Ti?ng Vi?t` as result.

my table is in `utf8_general_ci`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to use SET NAMES to tell the function what charset you're using.
Try:

```
...
SET NAMES utf8 COLLATION utf8_general_ci;
SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(INPUT);
...
```

Manual reference:

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

> SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL
>   statements to the server. Thus, SET NAMES 'cp1251' tells the server,
>   “future incoming messages from this client are in character set
>   cp1251.” It also specifies the character set that the server should
>   use for sending results back to the client.

Not sure if you need to specify the collation in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.

I did add charset utf8 to input param and output and it works now.

    `CREATE FUNCTION CAP_FIRST (INPUT VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8)`

    `RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8`